# How to display a detailed badge profile on personal website

Tags: discussion, flair

How can I add a detailed  Stack Overflow badge on my website?

Comment: You have the "flair" link in your profile. Anything more and you would have to build your own with the API.

Answer (score 46):

You can go to your profile by clicking on your avatar/reputation/badges in the top bar, then click on **Edit Profile & Settings**, then navigate to the **flair** tab.

The page has instructions on how to add this to your website, including a HTML snippet that you can copy and paste.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: If you are logged in to SO, open a new tab and click [Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)